# How can I write a program that will take the input of three numbers and print the sum on the console?

Tags: c#, encoding, console, console-application

So basically my question is how I can write a program that will take the input of three numbers and display the sum on console?

I tried a few solutions and I watched a couple of Youtube videos, but still didn't quite understand.

Comment: Can you show us _what_ you have tried? Then we could help you understand _why_ that does not work, and how you may proceed.

Comment: Do like to pass the numbers as arguments in your command line? Or do you like to pass the numbers via console.readLine() ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can read the input from the console, convert it to an integer, calculate the sum, and then display the result in the console.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number: "); // Prints "Enter the first number:" in the console.
     var number1string = Console.ReadLine(); // Reads the input which the user supplies. This is a string.

     Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number: ");
     var number2string = Console.ReadLine();

     Console.WriteLine("Enter the third number: ");
     var number3string = Console.ReadLine();

     var number1 = int.Parse(number1string); // Convert the string from the user to an integer value
     var number2 = int.Parse(number2string);
     var number3 = int.Parse(number3string);

     var sum = number1 + number2 + number3; // Calculate the sum of the 3 inputs

     Console.WriteLine($"The sum of {number1}, {number2} and {number3} is: {sum}"); // Show the result in the console.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not homework and not passing values into the app but instead prompting for values consider the following code which by installing [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.46.0) NuGet package provides a method to get numbers with validation.

In the code below `TextPrompt<int>` means to get an int, if you want a double `TextPrompt<double>` etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Spectre.Console;

namespace YourNamespaceGoesHere
{
    partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] prompts =
            {
                "first", 
                "second", 
                "third"
            };

            List<int> list = new List<int>();

            for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
            {
                int value = AnsiConsole.Prompt(
                    new TextPrompt<int>($"[cyan]Enter {prompts[index]} number[/]")
                        .PromptStyle("yellow")
                        .ValidationErrorMessage("[white on red]Please enter a number[/]")
                        .DefaultValue(0)); ;

                list.Add(value);

                Console.Clear();
            }

            AnsiConsole.MarkupLine($"[white on blue]Total is {list.Sum()}[/]");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If using a library is not for you than consider the following where if the value entered is not a number the value is 0.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[] prompts =
    {
        "first",
        "second",
        "third"
    };

    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter {prompts[index]} number");

        var userValue = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(userValue, out var value))
        {
            list.Add(value);
        }

        Console.Clear();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Total is {list.Sum()}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Finally, for either solution to see the values entered `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));`

Answer (score -1):

```cs
// Paste that into your program.cs (dotnet 6)

// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var lineString = Console.ReadLine();

// lineString could be "123 456 789"

// now we split the numbers into an array
if (lineString != null && lineString.Length > 0)
{
    var splittedNumbers = lineString.Split();
    // splittedNumbers will look like:
    // splittedNumbers[0] -> 123
    // splittedNumbers[1] -> 456
    // splittedNumbers[2] -> 789

    // now we need to transform the string into an number and add summarize it
    var sumNumber = 0;
    foreach (var split in splittedNumbers)
    {
        var number = 0;
        // try to parse your input if possible - without throwing an arror
        int.TryParse(split, out number);
        sumNumber += number;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Your sum: " + sumNumber.ToString());
}

// Append that to let the console not quid directly without sseing the sum....
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Your solution is a bit complex for a beginner. However, it will work.